# 22.04 LTS - suggested programs to be installed

Tags: 22.04

When installing 22.04 and logging in for the first time, a window with suggested programs to be installed from the “Ubuntu Software” is shown.

I had to restart, and now I am not able to run that welcome window again.

Could you help on how to show that list of recommended programs again?

Many thanks.

Comment: Did you install server? It suggests this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Tasksel I use Kubutnu, but did not think any desktop flavors suggest software, but may refer you to the Software Center which should be in your menu. I prefer synaptic (you have to install that), but not as user friendly, but has more detail on what you are installing.

Comment: Don't arbitrarily just install a bunch of software because somebody/something suggests that you do. Install only what you NEED... else you'll end up back here with a broken system.

Comment: That list looked quite promising - not planning to install what is there for the sake of having been pre-selected by the Ubuntu team, it is just that the list looked good enough!

Answer (score 0):

If you really just want to hunt and peck for software, you can open the Ubuntu Software app and browse around. However, this isn't necessarily a good idea - while Canonical doesn't purposefully allow malicious software into the Snap store, at least one cryptominer has sneaked through before.

Stick with the software you have. When you discover you need your computer to do something, then Google "do xyz on Ubuntu", and hunt around for **actively maintained, well-trusted** software that does what you want. I'd prefer open-source software over closed-source software. If you need to edit video, you want to use Kdenlive (or another well trusted video editor), not Joe Bob's Super Awesome Random Video Editor. (Kdenlive is actually a well-known and trusted video editor, I made the other one up.)

Just so I actually answer the question you asked, I don't know how to get that intro screen back, but here's the list of apps a brand new Ubuntu 22.04 installation suggested to me after a fresh install. Again, don't just install stuff because it looks cool - install stuff that you actually need. Here's the list:

- code
- zoom-client
- spotify
- Slack
- pycharm_community
- Android Studio
- Microsoft Teams - Preview
- Krita
- plexmediaserver
- VLC
- OBS Studio
- GNU Image Manipulation Program
- GitKraken
- Discord
- 0ad

Comment: Thanks a lot for the list and the good advice !